# Loop through results of one query and insert them into another, joining with union all results of 2nd query

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a query that I would really appreciate any bit of help on.

I have a first query that selects the job_types in one table (26 results). These job_type names all relate to a separate table that is the same name as them. Then, I need to use this result (the list of job_types) to call a new query on all the related job_type tables - looping through the results from the first query, inserting them in to the second query, and I am trying to UNION the results and output them into a table. But I'm stuck with the loop. My code so far is:

```
$sql = "";
$union = "";
$tables = [];

$q = "SELECT DISTINCT job_table 
        FROM job_type 
        WHERE job_type NOT IN (26, 28) AND status = 1";

$tables[] = $conn->query($q);
print_r($tables);

/*while ($table = $tables->fetch_assoc()) {
            $sql .= "SELECT 
                    DATE(call_time) AS `date`,
                    COUNT(*) AS  `sub_total`,
                    '$table->job_table' AS `table` 
                FROM '$table->job_table'
                WHERE table.show IS TRUE AND call_time BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate
                AND table.processing_complete IS TRUE
                GROUP BY `date`";
            }*/

foreach ($tables AS $table) {
    $sql .= $union . "SELECT 
                    DATE(call_time) AS `date`,
                    COUNT(*) AS  `sub_total`,
                    '$table' AS `table`
                FROM '$table'
                WHERE table.show IS TRUE AND call_time BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate
                AND table.processing_complete IS TRUE
                GROUP BY `date`";
    $union = " UNION ";

}
```

I know I need to put in a loop, in order to union the tables and run through them until the final one, so the WHILE loop is something I was trying out, as is the FOREACH loop. I'm only learning (slowly) PHP and would much appreciate any assistance.

**EDIT**
I have added the following code to the end to try and get it to display.

```
$results = $conn->query($sql);
}
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"<TABLE><TR><TD>". $row["date"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["sub_total"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["table"] . "</TD></TR>";
    }
```

However, then I run it, I am returning the following error - 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string' on the '$table' AS `table` line.

Comment: *"But I'm stuck!! "*: please describe the problem you are having. Being stuck is not very enlightening.

Comment: I have added the edit above, apologies for being general. I am unsure regarding the loop I need @trincot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you put in comments was the better attempt, so I will focus on that code block.

Some issues:

- The `query` method returns a result object. You should not assign it to `$tables[]`, which would make `$tables` an array with one result object. Just assign the result to `$tables`.
- The `fetch_assoc` method makes your records available as associative records, so you should not use the object notation `$table->`, but brackets: `$table[ ... ]`.
- The `FROM` clause in SQL should not be followed by something in quotes, but by the name itself, so don't put single quotes there
- When you embed expressions in a double quoted string, you need to wrap them in braces, like `{$table[...]}`. Without those braces you can only embed atomic variables, like `$startDate`.
- In MySql SQL dates must be quoted (I assume `$startDate` and `$endDate` are strings)
- In SQL the `IS` operator is really intended in combination with `NULL`, not with another value. What's more, checking equality with `TRUE` is often overkill, as you could just test the expression on the left of the equality
- To join the different SQL snippets with `UNION`, you could first collect them in an array, and then apply `implode` to that. Also: `UNION ALL` has better performance, and makes no difference in your case.

Corrected code:

```
// *** query method returns a result object, not an array:
$tables = $conn->query($q);

while ($table = $tables->fetch_assoc()) {
    // *** Use {$ ... } notation, with bracket access, not '->'.
    // *** Quote dates. Do not quote tables. Omit "IS TRUE".
    // *** Collect into array. The `UNION` can be added later.
    $sql[] = "
        SELECT 
                DATE(call_start_time) AS `date`,
                COUNT(*) AS  `sub_total`,
                '{$table[job_processing_table]}' AS `table` 
        FROM    {$table[job_processing_table]}
        WHERE   table.show
        AND     call_start_time BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
        AND     table.processing_complete
        GROUP BY `date`";
}

// *** Add UNION:
$sql = implode(" UNION ALL ", $sql)
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I have made those changes as you suggested however I am now returning the following notice - Notice: Use of undefined constant job_processing_table - assumed 'job_processing_table' .. Do you have any idea why this would be returned? Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, but maybe that behaviour depends on the PHP version. Try putting single quotes around `job_processing_table` in both occurrences in the SQL.

Comment: That's great, now I just have to out put the results! Many thanks for your help